# Python 3 boolean condition prints false instead of true

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

Why is this happening?

```
>>> print(1==1 & 6<9)
False
>>> print(1==1 & 5<9)
True
```

Comment: `&` is bitwise and. Python uses `and`

Comment: `1&6` is 0. `1&5` is 1.

Comment: Also, `&` binds stronger than comparisons, so you are not testing `(1==1) & (6<9)` but `1 == (1 & 6) < 9`, i.e. `1 == 0 and 0 < 9`

Comment: does && operator works

Comment: No, that is in Javascript.

Comment: @Amarjeet No, just use `and`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1==1&6<9,` here & will evaluated first.
`1&6` is bitwise and, will evaluate to 0.
`1&5` is bitwise and, will evaluate to 1.

```
1==1&6<9 => 1==0<9
1==1&5<9 => 1==1<9
```

According to chaining (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) both will evaluate to:

```
1==0 and 0 < 9 ==> False 
1==1 and 1 < 9 ==> True
```

Answer (score 2):

& is bitwise and, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators.
Everything not 0 will be true. You need “and” instead of “&”.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you intend to combine multiple conditions, so you should use logical operator "and" not "&" which is a bitwise operator.

Change your code to the following:

```
print(1==1 and 6<9)
print(1==1 and 5<9)
```